# how to login to youtube and save cookies? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have this code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim logincookie As New CookieContainer


    Dim postData As String = "continue=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26feature%3Dheader%26nomobiletemp%3D1%26hl%3Den_US%26next%3D%252F&service=youtube&uilel=3&dsh=-5804339713411277263&ltmpl=sso&hl=en_US&GALX=kpcgpuXEK94&pstMsg=1&dnConn=&checkConnection=youtube%3A4148%3A1&checkedDomains=youtube&timeStmp=&secTok=&Email=" & user_fb.Text & "&Passwd=" & pass_fb.Text & "&signIn=Sign+in&PersistentCookie=yes&rmShown=1"
    Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
    Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
    Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)


    Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth"), HttpWebRequest)
    postReq.Method = "POST"
    postReq.KeepAlive = True
    postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
    postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    postReq.Referer = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth"
    postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
    postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length
    Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
    postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    postreqstream.Close()
    Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse

    logincookie = tempCookies
    postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)


    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())

    Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = thepage


End Sub
```

trying to make a tool for youtube upload video but it seems to have a cookies problem when I try to sign in !

it says that cookies must be allowed to run this action !
how can I enable cookies ?

Comment: vb.net is not the same as vb6. Please remove the irrelevant tag.

Answer (score 0):

Define one more Cookie container in the beginning:

```
Dim oRequestCookie As New CookieContainer
```

Try to add

```
 CType(postReq, HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = oRequestCookie
```

When you are defining the HttpWebRequest parameters. 
And then at the end you can extract the login cookie as you already did.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that your refer page should put some cookies in user machine 
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth

then when your try to login google check for these cookies before you could login and as now google will find to cookies. The Solution is to access your refer page first and make sure to use `CookieContainer` in that page then call your code and it will work 100%.

Try to solve the problem logically then move to think about errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
...

Dim galx As New Cookie
galx.Name = "GALX"
galx.Value = "something"
galx.Domain = ".google.com"
Dim postData As String = "GALX=something&continue=http%3A%2F......

...

tempCookies.Add(galx)
```

I was searching exactly this "youtube login" thing. I got same message on webbrowser1 with "grudolf"s code. Then i looked firefox's "tools/developer console" while log in to youtube. There was a cookie collection with members "ACCOUNT_CHOOSER", "GALX", "GAPS" etc... When i add a cookie named "GALX" with any vale and add same into post data, result was OK. I just added code. I hope it will help...

Comment: this is not a answer of question remove this answer.

Comment: i was searching exactly this "youtube login" thing. i got same message on webbrowser1. then i looked firefox's "tools/developer console" while log in to youtube. there was a cookie collection with members "ACCOUNT_CHOOSER", "GALX", "GAPS" etc... when i add a cookie named "GALX" with any vale and add same into post data, result was OK. i only wrote above addition code for answer. i hope it will help...